# App Update doesn't show up under 'App Store Updates'

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Apple just approved my update for my app but it doesn't show under the updates page of the app store. You have to manually go to the app page on the store and there is a cloud icon that appears that will download the update. 
I named the first version of my app 6.1 for some reason, don't know why. And my update is version 2.0. Is this the reason? And if so, can i change the version number of the first to 1.0.

Comment: How long ago was it approved? There's most likely a delay.

Comment: like ten minutes ago haha @Carcigenicate

Comment: I would be surprised if Apple was that punctual. I would have waited a day at least if it were my first time dealing with an update.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple never publishes the updates / new apps right after *ready for sale*. You have to be a bit patient and wait for about a day or something.

Also, it does not matter how you name your app versions. It can be whatever number you want it to be. Apple just recommends using numbers that make sense but they won't do anything about it.

Hope that helps :)